# OverflowError fig.savefig() triggered by dpi

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have ran into OverflowErrors from Matplotlib a few times. As an easy solution, I found to increase the chuncksize:

```
matplotlib.use('Agg')
matplotlib.rcParam['agg.path.chuncksize'] = 20000000 # 20M
```

For a timeseries plot with datetime index of 64k samples, I can save a figure without specifying the dpi.
After a certain threshold (somewhere around dpi=260), I trigger the OverflowError.

I thought this was quite interesting cause I thought this error was only caused by too many samples in timeseries. Can anyone explain me why this is and whether this is an issue or whether I just use a too high dpi?

Python 3.9.1, Matplotlib 3.3.3, Windows 10

---

Edit: Code to reproduce

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.use('Agg')
matplotlib.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 20000000

x = np.linspace(0, 100, 100000)
y = np.random.randint(1, 100, 100000)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)

try:
    fig.savefig('Figure.png', format='png')
    print('Successfully plotted without dpi')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
try:
    fig.savefig('Figure.png', format='png', dpi=500)
    print('Successfully plotted with high dpi')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Results for me in:

```
Successfully plotted without dpi
Exceeded cell block limit (set 'agg.path.chunksize' rcparam)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Could you please show some sample data, so that the error is triggered and reproducible?

Comment: Added the code and result

Comment: Thank you. Result is the same for me.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Do you know whether this is expected behaviour?

Comment: I don't think so. Reading through the mpl bugtracker at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5907 I think your workaround doesn't work in this case. It might be worth opening a ticket there.